# Remove phpmyadmin from Centos7

Tags: yum, centos7

I did a general yum install command on my Centos7 server, and got phpmyadmin 4.4 - I want version 4.6

**How do I cleanly remove phpmyadmin version 4.4 before installing the new version?** I am running php7, and the phpmyadmin 4.4 added many php5.4 files, some of which conflict with my php installation.

Answer (score 4):

**Remove phpmyadmin:**

```
yum remove phpmyadmin
```

**Be aware:**
It will not delete the /etc/httpd/conf.d/phpMyAdmin.conf file but it will change it to phpMyAdmin.conf.rpmsave

Same for /etc/phpMyAdmin/config.inc.php.rpmsave

Answer (score 0):

I you are using centos 7 I believe you are using apache web server **Apache/2.4.6** **(CentOS).** I usually provision centos with the epel repositories.

the version that is installed by default (using the terminal is 4.4.15)
when you install phpmyadmin using terminal it creates a file in **/etc/httpd/conf.d/phpMyAdmin.conf**

If you take a closer look to this file it has the php configuration where the phpmyadmin files are located in the server. (**/usr/share/phpMyAdmin**).
[Phpmyadmin configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HfuN5.gif)

this are possible solutions:

1) download the version that you would like to have (phpMyadmin 4.6) and download it to the root of the web folder (var/www/html/phpMyAdmin) restart the server and you will be able to access phpmyadmin directly

2) you can download the php source from phpmyadmin official page to this folder  /usr/share/phpMyadmin4.6
2.1) edit the configuration file to point to 4.6 php myadmin   /etc/httpd/conf.d/phpMyAdmin.conf.
2.2) restar the server and try http://ip-to-server/phpMyAdmin

Hope it helps

Comment: I looked in the folder **/etc/httpd/conf.d** - could not find a phpMyAdmin.conf file. I did see a **php.conf** file. I went to the website **http://ip-to-server/phpmyadmin** and got the login page for phpMyAdmin. I tried to login with my root credentials (don't know an alternate username). I was denied access. I think that I need to create a user and password, but isn't that part of the setup steps? If there is no **phpMyAdmin.conf** file, how can I bring up the login page with my internet browser?

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to delete phpMyadmin

```
yum remove phpMyAdmin.noarch
```

[remove phpMyAdmin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tF5gZ.png)

Or

```
rpm -qa |grep phpMyAdmin
rpm -e rpm -e phpMyAdmin-4.4.15.10-2.el7.noarch
```

[Remove phpMyAdmin with rpm](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kyhnf.png)